# Buffered Multipart Form Posts in Ruby

Tags: ruby, http, forms, networking, multipartform-data

I am currently using `Net::HTTP` in a Ruby script to post files to a website via a multipart form post.  It works great for small files, but I frequently have to send very large files using this script, and `HTTP#post` only seems to accept post data as a `String` object, which means that the file I'm sending has to be read into memory before anything can be sent.  This script is running on a busy production server, so it's unacceptable to gobble up hundreds of megabytes of RAM just to send a file.

Ideally, there'd be a method that could be given a buffer size and an `IO` object, and would send off buffer-sized chunks of data, reading from the `IO` object only as required.  What would be the best way to make this happen?  Did I miss something relevant in `Net::HTTP`?

**Update**: `Net::HTTP#body_stream(input)` looks good, though the documentation is rather... sparse.  Anyone able to point me to a good example of this in action?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Net::HTTP#body_stream(input)

Example for [multipart post without streaming](http://trac-git.assembla.com/breakout/browser/lib/trac2assembla.rb#L517):

Comment: This link is broken

Answer (score 3):

Actually I managed to upload a file using body_stream. The full source code is here:
http://stanislavvitvitskiy.blogspot.com/2008/12/multipart-post-in-ruby.html

Comment: I ultimately just dug through the Net/HTTP source code to figure out how to use body_stream, which was a right pain.  The modifications I made to the multipart code I posted in response to that other question ended up looking a lot like yours.  Shame it isn't built in.